# How to remove a border on hover

Tags: html, css

I have 3 cards, and it has right border. Now, if I hover on any card, we show box shadow. But still the right border is visible, of the sibling card. How can I remove it?
Here is the [link](https://codepen.io/saiyamjain143/pen/mdMEPQw) to my CodePen

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.grid>div:last-child {
  border: none;
}

.card {
  padding: 1rem;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 12px #ccc;
  border-radius: $radius;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="card">
    <div>Lorem, ipsum.</div>
    <div>Aut, dolor.</div>
    <div>Neque, quia?</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div>Lorem, ipsum.</div>
    <div>Aut, dolor.</div>
    <div>Neque, quia?</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div>Lorem, ipsum.</div>
    <div>Aut, dolor.</div>
    <div>Neque, quia?</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a trick where you add selector to the card next to the card you are hovering and change your `border-right` to `border-left`

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.card {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.card+.card {
  border: none;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 12px #ccc;
  border-radius: $radius;
  border-color: transparent;
}

.card:hover+.card {
  border-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="card">
    <div>Lorem, ipsum.</div>
    <div>Aut, dolor.</div>
    <div>Neque, quia?</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div>Lorem, ipsum.</div>
    <div>Aut, dolor.</div>
    <div>Neque, quia?</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div>Lorem, ipsum.</div>
    <div>Aut, dolor.</div>
    <div>Neque, quia?</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If you use Scss it will be

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.card {
  padding: 1rem;
  &+.card {
    border: none;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
}


.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 12px #ccc;
  border-radius: $radius;
  border-color: transparent;
  &+.card {
    border-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove:
`border-right: 1px solid #ccc;`